# Generate a 100 Hz Clock from a 50 MHz Clock in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog

I have a DE0 board with a 50 Mhz clock that am I trying to to bring down to 100 Hz in Verilog. Could anyone help me with the code to do this?

Comment: You can use a pll (e.g. in Qsys) to generate a clock that you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Build an 18 bit counter.  Every time it hits 250,000, toggle a flip-flop.  50 MHz / 250,000 = 200 Hz.  Toggling a pin at 200 Hz gives you 100 Hz with a 50 percent duty cycle.  If you just need a pulse with a 100 Hz repetition frequency, then build a 19 bit counter and generate a pulse when it hits 500,000.

Fortunately 250,000 and 500,000 are both even integers.  Generating a perfect 50 percent duty cycle with an odd divisor means that you need to flip the output on on a rising edge and off on a falling edge.  On a Xilinx FPGA, this can be done with an ODDR/ODDR2 and a counter with a little head scratching to get the D0/D1 inputs set correctly.  This only works for sending the signal out of the chip through an I/O pin, though, as the output of an ODDR/ODDR2 cannot be used within a design.  A pulse is really all you need inside a design, though.

Generating anything with a non-integer ratio is more complicated.  If it is a rational fraction, you may be able to use a PLL or DDS to help out, either by itself or in combination with a counter.  If it isn't a rational fraction, then you are more or less out of luck unless you can approximate it with a rational fraction.  If a PLL is unavailable, will not go low enough, or you can't get the right ratio from a PLL and counter combination, then you can use a fractional DDS.  The idea with a fractional DDS is you add a constant to an accumulator on every clock cycle and toggle the output when the accumulator rolls over.  This will produce an output with a bit of jitter, but it can produce a precise frequency on average.  To produce a 100 Hz 50 percent duty square wave with a 32 bit accumulator, all you need to do is add 100*2^32/50e6 = 8589.93459 ~= 8590 each clock cycle.  The MSB of the accumulator will toggle at 50e6/(2^32*8590) = 100.00076145 Hz.  The larger the accumulator, the more accurate this will be.  The frequency resolution of a 32 bit accumulator is quite good - if you go up or down by 1 LSB, you get either 98.989119 or 100.012403 Hz.  However, you will get +/- 1 clock period of what is called deterministic jitter.  In other words, the edges are quantized by clock period and so could be up to 1/2 clock period early or late.  Unlike regular jitter, if you view deterministic jitter on an oscilloscope, you will see a very bimodal distribution of cycle times with two or more discrete averages, as opposed to one smooth distribution.  Also, since the .00076145 is an offset and not an average, the phase will slowly shift with respect to the system clock.  This may or may not be tolerable in your application.

Example verilog to generate 100 Hz from 50 MHz with a 50% duty cycle:

```
// generate 100 Hz from 50 MHz
reg [17:0] count_reg = 0;
reg out_100hz = 0;

always @(posedge clk_50mhz or posedge rst_50mhz) begin
    if (rst_50mhz) begin
        count_reg <= 0;
        out_100hz <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (count_reg < 249999) begin
            count_reg <= count_reg + 1;
        end else begin
            count_reg <= 0;
            out_100hz <= ~out_100hz;
        end
    end
end
```

Example verilog to generate a 100 Hz repetition 10 ns pulse from a 50 MHz clock:

```
// generate 100 Hz pulse chain from 50 MHz
reg [18:0] count_reg = 0;
reg out_100hz = 0;

always @(posedge clk_50mhz or posedge rst_50mhz) begin
    if (rst_50mhz) begin
        count_reg <= 0;
        out_100hz <= 0;
    end else begin
        out_100hz <= 0;
        if (count_reg < 499999) begin
            count_reg <= count_reg + 1;
        end else begin
            count_reg <= 0;
            out_100hz = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Example verilog to generate a 10 MHz output with 50% duty cycle from a 250 MHz clock with an ODDR2 on a Spartan 6:

```
// generate 10 MHz from 250 MHz
// 25 cycle counter, falling edge interpolated
reg [4:0] count_reg = 0;
reg q0 = 0;
reg q1 = 0;

always @(posedge clk_250mhz or posedge rst_250mhz) begin
    if (rst_250mhz) begin
        count_reg <= 0;
        q0 <= 0;
        q1 <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (count_reg < 24) begin
            count_reg <= count_reg + 1;
        end else begin
            count_reg <= 0;
        end
        q0 <= count_reg < 12;
        q1 <= count_reg < 13;
    end
end

ODDR2
clk_10mhz_out_oddr2_inst
(
    .Q(clk_10mhz_out),
    .C0(clk_250mhz),
    .C1(~clk_250mhz),
    .CE(1),
    .D0(q0),
    .D1(q1),
    .R(0),
    .S(0)
);
```

Example verilog code to generate 100 Hz from 50 MHz with a 50% duty cycle using an accumulator:

```
// generate 100 Hz from 50 MHz
reg [31:0] count_reg = 0;
wire out_100hz = count_reg[31];

always @(posedge clk_50mhz or posedge rst_50mhz) begin
    if (rst_50mhz) begin
        count_reg <= 0;
    end else begin
        count_reg <= count_reg + 8590; //(((100 * 1 << 32) + 50000000/2) / 50000000)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a DDS is limited to rational multiples of the references the same as a PLL is. If only because the registers used to program it have no way to express irrational numbers. The precision available might be greater on a DDS, but even a fractional-N PLL with a 16-bit denominator gives an precision better than 20 ppm, which is better than the reference accuracy will be in many designs.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with a DDS if it doesn't need to be exactly accurate.  A 32 bit DDS generating 100 Hz from 50 MHz will give you 100.00076145 Hz.  That's 7.6 ppm. Now, this is an offset and not an average, so that may or may not be a problem depending on the application - the phase will very slowly drift wrt. the reference oscillator.

Comment: Yes, but it's still a rational multiple of the reference, right? Your answer implied that DDS's aren't limited to rational multiples. If there's a way to program a DDS to have \$f_{ref} / \sqrt{2}\$ or \$f_{ref} / \pi\$ output frequency, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see what you're getting at.  A DDS is still a rational fraction, but usually you can get a whole lot more fractional bits with a DDS than you can with an FPGA-based fractional PLL.